# An alternative to Windows Picture and Fax Viewer for printing pictures

Tags: windows-7, windows, printing, photos, printing-software

Windows XP's good old Windows Picture and Fax Viewer was awesome for letting an inexperienced user to print a picture. You select a picture, select print, then follow the wizard, select which thumbnails to print, say the photo format, printer options, and finish. You need more prints? Just press back, and all the printer settings are retained!

Windows 7 version, instead, it's too simple, you cannot deselect a print, you cannot go back and print another copy, the printer settings are not retained, the adapt or crop is not intuitive, and so on.

I need an alternative to let an inexperienced user to print pictures quickly as a daily task

I tried Picasa, but, while better than Windows 7 photo viewer, it's not ok

Do you have suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I am using a little tool called IrfanView since Windows 2k. It´s freeware so maybe you just give it a try and test if it supports your needs ;-)
You can download it [here at the official homepage.](http://irfanview.tuwien.ac.at/)

Comment: Been using Irfanview for many years. It's lightweight and very versatile.

Comment: Unfortunately, irfanview it's too feature-rich to be used by inexperienced users, in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

I agree the one in XP was fast and simple with all the right features for quick printing and viewing, why did they screw it up in Vista and W7, I will never know. If you have Microsoft Office Installed try the Office Picture Manager, or try FastStone Image Viewer

http://www.faststone.org/

Answer (score 0):

In WinXP the Windows Picture and Fax Viewer had a silly name, however it was very useful for more than just pictures. In combination with a PDF printer (like CutePDF) it could be used to combine multiple files of different types with multi-select from Windows Explorer. I have not found a viable app with this functionality bundled into Win7 or Win10.